# Sending request with headers to third parts api with WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, flux, spring-webflux

I really like the solution I have with `RestTemplate` but soon it will be depreciated with future spring releases. I am trying to send some text to a third party api using `WebClient`

```
  String text = URLEncoder.encode(text,"UTF-8");

        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .defaultHeader("Key","af999-e99-4456-b556-4ef9947383d")
            .defaultHeader("src", srcLang)
            .defaultHeader("tgt", tgtLang)
            .defaultHeader("text", text)
            .build();
```

Then send a post here:

```
Mono<String> response = webClient.post().uri("/google/rtv/text")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Trying to parse based off of the legacy response:

```
private String parseJson( Mono<String> response) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = null;
        JsonNode review = null;


        //TODO: create an object and map it here. We need to save the original review too.
        try {
            root = mapper.readTree(response.toString());
            review = root.path("message");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return review.asText();
    }
```

Later I need to parse the response but right now I am getting an error saying:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'MonoFlatMap': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (String)"MonoFlatMap"; line: 1, column: 23]
```

and later:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

**What I am trying to accomplish is something like I have done with `RestTemplate`.**

Like so:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromUriString(URL)
            .queryParam("src", src)
            .queryParam("tgt", tgt)
            .queryParam("text", text);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

then set my header for the subscription globally.

```
  private ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
                                         ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        request.getHeaders().add("Key","af999-e99-4456-b556-4ef9947383d");
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        return response;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(this::intercept));
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Advice?

Comment: from the look of it, it seems Jackson is trying to serialize the returned `Mono`. Could you provide more context to where that `Mono` is being used and how?

Comment: Then where is that `Mono<String>` being used and how? I'm asking that because the source of the problem might be there, not in your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens here:

`root = mapper.readTree(response.toString());`

This code snippet is trying to serialize a `Mono<String>` as a String, when a `Mono` is a reactive type that can provide that `String` value eventually.

You could call `response.block()` and getting the resulting `String`, but this would be a blocking call and Reactor forbids that if in the middle of a reactive execution. This is done for good reasons, since this will block one of the few threads that your web application is using and can cause it to stop serving other requests.

You could instead have something like:

```
Mono<String> review = response.map(r -> parseJson(r);
```

And then reuse that new value down the line.

Note that `WebClient` natively supports JSON deserialization and you could deserialize the whole payload like so:

```
Mono<Review> review = webClient.post().uri("/google/rtv/text")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Review.class);
```